# Can't remove margin in CSS (Summernote, MVC, .NET)

Tags: css, .net, block, margin, summernote

I'm having trouble removing a margin in CSS .

I am working in a MVC .NET project and have implemented the summernote editor.
It  uses the following CSS files:

```
summernote.css
font-awesome.css
bootstrap.css
```

as well as the default css files for an MVC application.

I have inspected the page and it states I have a margin to the right on the `.note-editor` class. I have then set the margin to 0 for that div (and class), but so far it has been impossible to remove it.

Here is the link to my screenshot (since I require 10 reputation to post images):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtoxO.jpg

I would be more than grateful if someone could help!

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: it's now sorted - check answer below. Thanks for helping though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found what the problem was. The `.note-editor` was displaying as a block.
I changed its styling to `display:inline-block` and `width:95%`. This fixed it nicely. Thanks to everyone for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `margin` it is just the empty space inside the container `.col-md-10` which is shown in screenshot. For better understanding I created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/pxsxtc58/)

Here the parent element `.container` has some `max-width` and it is aligned center and the inner element `.inner-container` has `max-width: 90%;` and there is a remaining space of `10%`. If you inspect it you will see it as `orange` same as your example, which you thought it as margin.

In your scenario, the parent element `.col-md-10` has some `width` and the inner element `.note-editor` has `max-width:95%`. Here, there is a remaining space of `5%` which you assumed it as `margin`.

To remove it, remove `max-width` or if you give `max-width:100%` or `width: 100%`, your issue will be resolved.

Comment: It makes total sense. But if I cange the width of my col-md-10 it totally changes my layout. All I want to do is to get my info glyphicon aligned the same way the other two are. And if you say this 5% space is assumed to be a margin, why is it only on this div and not the other two?

Comment: Thanks for your comment it helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The following css worked for me.

```
.note-editor{
             display: inline-block;
             border: none;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in Site.css file or try directly to type style="margin 0 0 0 0" or try to apply another class to current.

Comment: Did that initially, still didn't work but now it's fixed :). Thanks anyways!